# After executing Linq query hitting the catch method unknwingly

Tags: entity-framework, linq, visual-studio-code

I got the below error after executing Linq code in Catch method,

> > 'Invalid column name Auxiliary Code'.

Initially the executed linq code given in Custom layer is below,

```
query = appDb.AuxiliaryAccount.AsNoTracking()
.Select(c => new PayrollItemLOV
 {
 AuxiliaryId = c.AuxiliaryAccountId,
 AuxiliaryCode = c.AuxiliaryAccountCode,
 AuxiliaryName = c.AuxiliaryAccountName,
 Active = c.Active                                     
 }).AsQueryable().OrderBy(jtSorting);
```

After executing the above query I got 4 rows as result.
But after further executing the below code in custom layer , it is hitting the catch method in Controller unknowingly.

```
jtableReturnTypeObj.Records = query.Skip(jtStartIndex).Take(jtPageSize).ToList();
```

After executing above code in custom it  is hitting the catch method in controller.
In catch Exception ex, I am getting error message as,

> > Invalid column name 'Auxiliary Code'

Please suggest me solution for the same.

Comment: Does the table(s) behind `appDb.AuxiliaryAccount` have a column named 'Auxiliary Code'?

Comment: No. Table columns have names such as AuxiliaryAccountCode and AuxiliaryAccountName.

Answer (score 0):

Your call to `.AsQueryable()` may be at fault here.
As far as I can see, it shouldn't be necessary, `.Select()` should already be returning a `Queryable<PayrollItemLOV>`.